# select from a mysql table records that belong to today

Tags: php, mysql

i have a field in my table called `time` its INT and iam using php time() function
now i want select all records that its `time` is today

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT time FROM table WHERE DATE(column) = CURDATE();
```

Check the following link :

- [Retrieve records by current date from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086297/mysql-query-retrieve-current-date-query)

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time >= '".strtotime("today")."' AND time < '".strtotime("tommorow")."'";
```

Comment: With this solution, mysql has to do two comparisons per row but no conversions (timestamp > date). The other solutions mentioned here require only one comparison but have to convert timestamp to date on every row. You have to decide/test what suits your application better.

Comment: Welp, if one would want to play it dirty, they could just compare time LIKE 'YYYY-MM-DD%' which only has a variable part by the right and will be blazingly fast if the column has an index.

Comment: @Konerak but the column is INT, not DATETIME.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where DATE(`time`) = DATE(NOW());
```