# query to check the timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In my java project I want to list the values of a table

**programtable**.

There are four fields **programid**, **programname**, **startdate** and **enddate** in table.

I want to list the details of programs done in today.

The startdate and enddate are in database datatype as **TIMESTAMP**. Help me to find the query to get the details of programs done on today.

I add my code to this. I use this method. But its not work,

```
String todayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
todayDatem=todayDate+" 00:00:00";
todayDaten=todayDate+" 23:59:59";
Timestamp timestamp1 = Timestamp.valueOf(todayDatem);
Timestamp timestamp2 = Timestamp.valueOf(todayDaten);
System.out.println("timestamp1:"+timestamp1+timestamp2);
String sql3 = "select * form programtable where startdate between '”+timestamp1+”' and '”+timestamp2+”'";  
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
List<programmodel> pgm = jdbcTemplate.query(sql3, ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(programmodel .class));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106474/select-from-a-mysql-table-records-that-belong-to-today Might help

Comment: If you have any code, please show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use placeholders instead of text dates in the query:

```
    java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    java.sql.Date d2 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24  * 3600 * 1000);
    String sql3 = "select * from programtable where startdate between ? and ?"; 
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
    List<programmodel> pgm = jdbcTemplate.query(sql3, ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(programmodel.class), d1, d2);
```

Comment: The startdate and enddate are in database in TIMESTAMP datatype. eg:2014-12-12 12:11:45 format. I edit my question. add some code

Comment: Thank you so much... I have some more doubt..When this project up, the server may be in another location may be in usa. When I use this code cause any problem. I think this will take system time.

Comment: 1) SQL driver ignores time part in java.sql.Date 2) test it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean started and finished today

```
 SELECT *
 FROM programtable
 WHERE startdate = CURDATE() AND enddate = CURDATE();
```

If you mean started today

```
 SELECT *
 FROM programtable
 WHERE startdate = CURDATE();
```

If you mean finished today

```
 SELECT *
 FROM programtable
 WHERE enddate = CURDATE();
```

Comment: sorry... dont get it.The startdate and enddate are in database in TIMESTAMP datatype. eg:2014-12-12 12:11:45 format.I add some code to my question. please check it.