# MySQL Query Date

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql query: retrieve current date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086297/mysql-query-retrieve-current-date-query)

I need a MySQL query that will select some data that contains todays date. I have built the following query:

```
SELECT CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor, CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha
FROM CRM_TRATATIVAS
GROUP BY CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor, CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha, CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria
HAVING (((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=10 Or (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=29 Or (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=32) AND ((CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)=Date()) AND ((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria)=14));
```

If I take the =Date() away, it works. Any ideas what the problem could be?

The final data show be something like this without the brackets and dots (I couldn't find how to make a table!

```
 Fecha                      Vendedor
 2012-12-03 10:12:13        (10)
 2012-12-03 12:14:16        (10)
 2012-12-03 09:15:46        (29)
 2012-12-03 13:35:56        (32)
```

---

Fixed!

I fixed by using this query.

```
SELECT CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor, CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha
FROM CRM_TRATATIVASGROUP BY CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor, CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha, CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria
HAVING (((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=10 Or (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=29 Or (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=32) AND ((DATE(CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)) = CURDATE()) AND ((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria)=14));
```

As Fecha was a `DATETIME` column, I added Date just before the reference to convert it into a date.

Comment: Can you confirm that `CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha` results in a date that is formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, it's YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: What is the datatype of `Fecha`? Is it `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: What exactly is the query supposed to do?

Comment: It is a DATETIME i think. It's a table from a CRM and what it's supposed to do is get a list of all the "Tratativas" the "Vendedores" code 10, 29 & 32 have done today. The "Tratativa" category is filtered to show only code 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha=Date()
```

with this:

```
DATE(CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)=CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE()` returns the current date, and `DATE(Fecha)` returns just the date part of `Fecha` (without hours, minutes and seconds). I also suggest you to write the query this way, that looks cleaner:

```
SELECT Distinct
  CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria,
  CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor,
  CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha
FROM
  CRM_TRATATIVAS
WHERE
  CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor in (10, 29, 32)
  AND DATE(CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha) = CURDATE()
  AND CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria=14
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer! Only my local IT guru found it before I saw this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want the following:

```
SELECT c.ID_Vendedor, c.Fecha
FROM CRM_TRATATIVAS c
WHERE c.ID_Vendedor IN (10, 29, 32) 
    AND c.Fecha = Curdate()
    AND c.ID_Categoria=14
-- GROUP BY c.ID_Vendedor, c.Fecha, c.ID_Categoria;
```

*Note: I updated this to use a `WHERE` instead of a `HAVING` clause.  The `HAVING` clause is for use when there is an aggregate function that you need to filter on.  Also I am not sure why you are using a `GROUP BY` clause you have no aggregate functions in your `SELECT` list*

If your date `Fecha` has date and time and you are only looking to match the date part, then you might want to use:

```
SELECT c.ID_Vendedor, c.Fecha
FROM CRM_TRATATIVAS c
WHERE c.ID_Vendedor IN (10, 29, 32) 
    AND Date(c.Fecha) = Curdate()
    AND c.ID_Categoria=14
-- GROUP BY c.ID_Vendedor, c.Fecha, c.ID_Categoria;
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` will remove duplicates.

Comment: @ypercube I agree that it will, that is why I only commented the clause out and not remove it.  I would probably use a `DISTINCT` over the `GROUP BY`

Comment: This is giving me a null answer. I have entries in the Fecha column, such as 2012-12-03 15:38:16. All answers are giving me the same.

Comment: @user1873567 can you edit your OP and post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
((CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)=Date())
```

to

```
((CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)=Date(NOW()))
```

The MySQL [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function requires a parameter, by itself it does not return the current date.  You can also just use the [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function instead of `DATE(NOW())`

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything missing from the query? I wouldn't probably use the GROUP BY/HAVING clauses, if you don't need a form of aggregate functions with it.

How about a query such as:

```
SELECT CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor, CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha
FROM CRM_TRATATIVAS
WHERE (((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=10 Or (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=29 Or
 (CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Vendedor)=32) AND ((CRM_TRATATIVAS.Fecha)=Date()) AND 
 ((CRM_TRATATIVAS.ID_Categoria)=14));
```