# How to allow user to vote once per day not for last 24hrs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to create function that allow users to vote only once in a day. For this I have created `ratingTimestamp` field in table in which I am inserting the current timestamp value at the voting time.

And for validating the users that he can vote only once per day. I am using this MySQL query:

```
SELECT count( * ) AS votecount
FROM ratings AS e
WHERE e.userId =5
AND e.ratingTimestamp >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1
DAY
```

The problem is that this query giving me `votecount` on 24hrs basis but I want it on the basis of date only.

Like if user voted on 12-03-2014 11:59:00 AM and again he tried for voting at 13-03-2014 4:00PM he can vote but with using the above query it is not possible because it is giving me vote count 1 for this case because it is counting the last 24hrs from 4:00PM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You should use something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT count( * ) AS votecount FROM ratings WHERE DATE(e.ratingTimestamp) = CURDATE()";
```

OR you can try through PHP

```
$sql="SELECT count( * ) AS votecount FROM ratings WHERE e.ratingTimestamp >= '".strtotime("today")."' AND e.ratingTimestamp < '".strtotime("tommorow")";
```

OR alternatively look into this link

[Retrieve records by current date from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086297/mysql-query-retrieve-current-date-query)